# How to import external fonts to the app at runtime in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, fonts, runtime

Is there a way to let user import font files like .ttf files at runtime to use them in the app?
I know how to add them to resources folder when developing the app to make them available any time. But I want to let user add his custom fonts to the app himself.

I have tried to import the font file using

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.type = "application/x-font-ttf"
startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
```

But how to use it? Does it need to copy the file to custom location to work or what?